# Euler-Lagrange - circle cone

Tags: mathematical-physics

> A mass point moves on the wall of a hollow circle cone under influence of the homogeneous gravitational field of earth.
>
> Use spherical coordinates to solve this problem.
>
> a)Set up the lagrange equations of second kind.
>
> b)If the lagrange function **L** isn't dependent on a coordinate **q** but on the associated velocity, then **q** is a cyclic coordinate. Is any of the generalized coordinates in this case a cyclic coordinate?
>
> c) Check if the momentum, the z-component of the angular momentum and the total energy are conserved.

First I tried drawing the situation as best as I could. This is what I got:

[image]

I was sick the past few weeks so I basically missed everything regarding lagrangian formalism. Since we use a text book as a script to go along to I tried reading in it, but all the copies in the school library were borrowed. So I had to make use of wikipedia.

I'm not yet familiar with the terminology. The lagrange equations of second kind are the euler-lagrange equations, right?

To be honest this topic doesn't stick with me, especially the general coordinates and velocities.

Anyways, I tried setting up $L=T-V$ since this is the first step as far as I could tell from the wiki entry.

Generally it should be $L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+\dot{z}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2)-mgz$, right?

$z=r\cot{\theta}$? Meaning, $L=\frac{1}{2}m((1+\cot^2(\theta))\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2)-mgr\cot{\theta})$, correct?
I hope someone could help me out here.

**Edit:**

@JohnHughes: I think you were right about r. Once I tried expressing the lagrangian in spherical coordinates as was asked it seemed reasonable to assume that r is actually the diagonal line closest to it.

So I got this:

a) $\vec{x}=r\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\\\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}\\\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}$

Since I need the velocity for the lagrangian, I have:

$\dot{\vec{x}}=\dot{r}\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\\\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}\\\cos{\theta} \end{bmatrix}+r\dot{\phi}\sin{\theta}\begin{bmatrix} -\sin{\phi}\\\cos{\phi}\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Plugging that all I have:
$T=\frac{m}{2}\dot{\vec{x}}^2=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2\sin^2{\theta})$ and $V=mgr\cos{\theta}$.
$L=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2\sin^2{\theta})-mgr\cos{\theta}$.

That should conclude a), right?

About b): Just from the given definition in b) I can say that $\phi$ is a cyclic coordinate since the lagrangian only has $\dot{\phi}$, correct?

About c): I'm not really sure how to approach this one. My ideas so far were:

**Momentum:** I can imagine that the momentum isn't conserved since the mass point is accelerated due to the gravitational field, but I have no idea how to write that down mathematically correct.

**Angular mometum:** To be honest I'm pretty much lost here.

**Total Energy:** Again I would guess that the total energy is conserved since the expressions for the kinetic and potential energy don't have a dependency on t (time)?

Comment: I think you want $z = r \cos \theta$ rather than the cotangent. Cosine is adjacent (z) over hypotenuse (r). Otherwise it looks as if you're headed in the right direction.

Comment: I think r is supposed to be the radius of each individual circle. Or not?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, Franie -- I was reading it as marking the diagonal line that it's closest to, but in that case, it doesn't make sense in the Lagrangian that you've written. So now that I understand it (D'oh!) your lagrangian looks fine. If you write out the Lagrangian expression (the thing involving $\partial L / \partial q$ for each of the generalized coordinates $q$ (i.e., for $r$ and $\phi$) you should get a pair of coupled differential equations that your particle must satisfy.

Comment: @JohnHughes I played around with this problem for the last hour and I think you were right about r. I made an edit in my post, could you read through it and see if I'm correct? And I'm really not sure how to deal with c) yet.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was thinking of "cylindrical polars", where $r$ would be the horizontal line. Anyhow, it makes almost no difference in your formulas, since $\theta$ is a constant. I believe your answer  to part "b" is correct, yes. As for part c -- I have no idea. Physics is not my strong suit, and Lagrangians were about the point where I stopped "getting it". :)

Comment: I feel the same way. I will try seeing if I can find similar questions with solutions on the internet. Maybe I will find something. By the way, thanks for all your help so far. I wouldn't have gotten so far without you.